# Counting how many instances are between a datetime interval in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe of the form

```
print(ts.head())

id    start_datetime            end_datetime
0   2018-09-19 00:00:00   2018-09-19 03:00:00
1   2018-09-19 01:00:00   2018-09-19 03:00:00
2   2018-09-19 01:30:00   2018-09-19 03:00:00
3   2018-09-19 02:14:00   2018-09-19 03:00:00
4   2018-09-19 02:23:00   2018-09-19 03:00:00
```

I want to make a dataframe with a datetime index (hourly frequency) with a single column. The column counts for each index how many of the original dataframe's rows include this index between their start_datetime and end_datetime values.

I started by making the df with hourly frequency that starts and ends at the appropriate times:

```
ts = df.select('start_datetime','end_datetime').toPandas()
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(freq="h", start="2018-09-19", end = '2018-11-18 
18:00:00')
df_hourly = pd.DataFrame(index=idx)
df_hourly.head()

        id
2018-09-19 00:00:00
2018-09-19 01:00:00
2018-09-19 02:00:00
2018-09-19 03:00:00
2018-09-19 04:00:00
```

Now I need for each row to count how many rows of the original dataframe it falls in between. I am trying to play with numpy on the values of the columns but I'm pretty sure there's a pretty pandas way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using `numpy` broadcast

```
s1 = df.start_datetime.values
s2 = df.end_datetime.values
s = df_hourly.index.values[:, None]
df_hourly['Value'] = np.sum((s1 <= s) & (s2 >= s), 1)
df['Value'] = np.sum((s1 <= s) & (s2 >= s), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, smart use of the sum indices to get two different meaningful results!